# I am stuck while writing MySQL query to submit the content of a form which has text & checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form that had text and dropdowns. Now the client wants to use checkbox instead of dropdown. How to I change the query . Here is my code:

Form is in `join.php`

```
<form name="pantryinfo" id="pantryForm" method = "post"  action="email.php" data-toggle="validator" role="form">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Pantry Name" required>

        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter Street address" >
                        <p class="help-block"></p>

        <input type="checkbox" id="snapeligible" name="snapeligible"  value="Yes">SNAP Eligilble<br>

        <label>Community Meal?
        select class="form-control" id="communitymeal" name="communitymeal" required >
                <option></option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
        </label>

        <input  name="submit" type="submit" id="submit"  value="Add Food Provider" class="btn btn-primary center-block">

</form>
```

The field `SNAP Eligilble` was a dropdown just like `Community Meal` but now is a check box.

My earlier query was as follows in `email.php`

```
    require 'config/connectDB.php';
    //set variables from the form
            $pname = $_POST['name'];
            $paddress = $_POST['address'];
            $psnapeligible = $_POST['snapeligible'];
            $pcommunitymeal = $_POST['communitymeal'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO temp(pan_id, pname, paddress, psanpeligible, pcommunitymeal, )  
VALUES(NULL,'$pname', '$paddress', '$psnapeligible', '$pcommunitymeal',)";
```

I am not sure how to append the query to include data from the check box only when the checkbox is selected as its not a required field.

Comment: Remove extra `,`

Comment: I have many oother fields in the query actually but all are text so did not include them. The `,` is just a typo here.

Comment: Its almost IMPOSSIBLE to debug pseudo or summarized code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unchecked checkbox will not even be found in the `$_POST` array. This means to see from the PHP side whether the box was checked, all you have to do is look at whether the matching variable is set.

Change:

```
$psnapeligible = $_POST['snapeligible'];
```

To:

```
$psnapeligible = isset($_POST['snapeligible']) ? 'yes' : 'ho';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an IF-Statement, where you proof if the Value of the Checkbox is set.

Is it set use this Statement
Else use the another Statement without the psnapeligible

```
if (isset ($psnapeligible)) {
     $sql = "...";
else  {
     $sql = "...";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can chek in your php page (email.php) if your chek box is set or not ...

```
if (isset($_POST['snapeligible'])) {
        $psnapeligible = $_POST['snapeligible'];
    }
else {
        $psnapeligible = "No" ;
    }
```